# PHP data to plot

Tags: php, html, plot, flot

I have the two arrays representing the x and y values but they just don't seem to be in the right format. I want to convert this:
[image: Wrong]

Into something like this:
[image: Right]

The code used for the first one is:

```
$dataset2[] = array(floatval($row["x"]),intval($row["y"]));
```

And for the second one is:

```
$dataset2[] = array(($x),($y));
```

In the second case I do have x and y as arrays of numbers and in the first case the mode of obtaining them is a bit different, and nope, unfortunately I can't just get the values as in the first case in the second one.

To convert it I use:

```
var dataset1 = <?php echo json_encode($dataset2); ?>;
```

In both cases. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this question similar to the question you asked five days ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31035311

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ..

```
var a = floatval($row["x"]);
var b = intval($row["y"]);

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    $dataset2[] = array(a[i],b[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing this format on arranging your array

```
$arr2 = array(

    array(
        array(1,2,3),
        array(1,2,3),
        array(1,2,3),
        array(1,2,3),

    ),
    array(
        array(1,2,3),
        array(1,2,3),
        array(1,2,3),
        array(1,2,3),

    ),
    array(
        array(1,2,3),
        array(1,2,3),
        array(1,2,3),
        array(1,2,3),

    ), 
);

echo json_encode($arr2);
```

Comment: Hmm could you be a little more accurate? It's a bit difficult to understand the syntax. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
    $x = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
    $y = array(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90);
    $arr1 = array();
    for($t = 0; $t < count($x); $t++){
        $arr[] = array($x[$t].",".$y[$t]); 
    }

    $val = json_encode($arr);
```